# Android dropping tcp connection when screen is off

Tags: android, tcp, xamarin

My Android app starts and keeps a TCP connection going within a Foreground service. The activity uses `StartService()` to start the service. Also the service is started in it's own process.

Here is the services `OnStartCommand`:

```
// Code is in C# using Xamarin but regular Java/Android answers are acceptable
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand (Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    base.OnStartCommand (intent, flags, startId);

    ...

    var ongoingNotification = new Notification (Resource.Drawable.icon, "Service running");
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity)), 0);
    ongoingNotification.SetLatestEventInfo (this, "Service", "The service is running.", pendingIntent);
    StartForeground ((int)NotificationFlags.ForegroundService, ongoingNotification);
    return StartCommandResult.RedeliverIntent;
}
```

The connection is fine when the phone's screen is on, whether or not an activity from my app is open or not. However less than 30 seconds after I turn the screen off I always lose tcp connection. My app reconnects automatically so I get the connection back, but it will continually disconnect when the screen is off. I turn it back on and it's fine, even if an activity from my app isn't open.

It could be connected to the Android Lifecycle but I just don't see how. Based on debug messages I write to a text file on the phone (the issue doesn't happen when a debugger from an IDE is attached), the service seems to be operating as it's supposed to but the connection just isn't being stable.

I've also tested this with and without the "Don't Keep Activities" in Developer options selected to no change. So it shouldn't have anything to do with the Activity Lifecycle at least.

Why is Android dropping my tcp connection, but only when the screen is off?

Comment: Did you acquire a wifi lock? Or are you on mobile?

Comment: The testing was done on wifi but the app can use either wifi or mobile. I'm not using a wifi lock (as I wasn't aware of it before you mentioned it). After a quick test on mobile it looks like the same issues occur for mobile as it does for wifi.

Comment: Options you'd have at this point would be acquiring a WakeLock or periodically waking up your app (through AlarmManager), then acquiring a WakeLook and do background updates. I would recommend the latter to maximize battery life. How often you wake up depends on how much background transfer your app needs to do. Ideally you would have the server send a push notification and your service respond by a poll request.

Comment: If that is indeed the solution, which I'll try, I feel like I'd have to always keep a WakeLock on my app. Between manual keep alives and required data being sent/received, my service is sending out and receiving data very frequently so the connection is in use every 10-15 seconds max. I don't see why it's shutting down the connections when they are in use.

Comment: It's shut down to keep the battery alive. The user (and usability) are the main concern in Android, not your app. Be aware that a permanent wakelock can render the phone useless as it'll reduce battery life.

Comment: Yeah, hopefully a permanent wakelock wont be the final solution but it's fine enough for a basic test to see if it will work at all. I'll have to do some testing with periodically waking my app and seeing if I can find something that will keep a stable connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by acquiring a Partial [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) while my service is running.

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

public override void OnCreate ()
{
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
    mWakeLock = pm.NewWakeLock (WakeLockFlags.Partial, "PartialWakeLockTag");
    mWakeLock.Acquire();
}

public override void OnDestroy ()
{
    mWakeLock.Release();
}
```

If I implement something more power efficient in the future, I'll update this answer.

Comment: Is there a way to do same thing in IOS?